# My shrinkwrap modifier is not being applied properly

Tags: subdivision-surface

I am trying to create a sleeve for my character. However, the shrink-wrap modifier is not being applied correctly. Whenever I extrude the edges to go around his bicep, it starts stretching and appears very jagged. Even if I manage to go around his entire bicep, when it comes to scaling it, it forces itself towards the center of my character. I'm trying to create a sleeve like the reference image. Along with the shrink-wrap modifier, I've added the subdivision surface, solidify and mirror.
[image]
[image]
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3804f57a22f6a5090fc715f18e33c03320210718200616/3215a4df3818ca54ede5af9505e4a2ca20210718200631/9d0d93

Comment: link to Halden's file: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3804f57a22f6a5090fc715f18e33c03320210718200616/3215a4df3818ca54ede5af9505e4a2ca20210718200631/9d0d93

Answer (score 0):

First, apply the *Mirror* modifier. The *Shrinkwrap* makes the sleeve stick not only to the arm but also to the body (torso), you should remove this modifier and use the *Snap* option instead.

Also your body mesh is a bit high-poly and messy, you should try to stay as low-poly as possible, with a good topology flow, it will make this kind of work much easier (and also the rigging and animation if you plan to animate).

Plus if you have a good topology you will be able to easily create a sleeve by a simple duplication of faces.